# Commandline arguments in Python

Tags: python

I'm expecting arguments in this format

```
filname.py -input="a","b","c"
```

currently, I'm parsing command line parameters by this code

```
dict(item.split("=") for item in sys.argv[1].split(" "))
```

is there any better way to read command line arguments. I tried using OptionParser but OptionParser requires key value pairs to be separated by space.

Comment: The goto is part of the standard library: [`argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a specific example of accumulating a list via [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html), which I mentioned in a comment above.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> args = parser.parse_args("--foo a --foo b --foo c".split())
>>> print(args.foo)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This is not quite as ideal, since this requires the argument name `--foo` to be given with each item you want to add to its list.

An alternative would be to read in a string with commas and split them:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> args = parser.parse_args("--foo a,b,c".split())
>>> args.foo
'a,b,c'
>>> args.foo.split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I suppose this may be an XY problem. What is it exactly that you are attempting to accomplish by having an argument with parameters like this?

---

After receiving further information (OP's comments), it appears that the key-value reading is vital.

The [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) project has a custom option-parsing module [`tornado.options`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/options.py) which assumes values to be given on the command line as key-value pairs like you want.

I would *not* advise you to import Tornado into your project just to get this to work. However, you can read through the [`OptionParser`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/options.html#optionparser-class) object's definition in that file I linked to see how you might implement such functionality. To simulate `argparse` using this new argument parser:

```
>>> from tornado.options import OptionParser
>>> parser = OptionParser()
>>> parser.define('foo', multiple=True)
>>> parser.parse_command_line('throwaway --foo="a","b","c"'.split())
>>> parser.foo
['"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
```

Notice that `parse_command_line` requires an extra throwaway argument at the beginning. This is because if you don't supply a value, it uses `sys.args` and skips the first argument (which is generally the name of the command being executed). In your own parser, you could rewrite [this line](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/options.py#L274) to start at `0` instead of `1` and avoid this necessity.

Conveniently, Tornado's `OptionParser` does include the ability to specify a list through the `multiple=True` parameter of `define`. You would still have to strip the resulting values of their extraneous quotation marks, but that's done simply enough.

Comment: A different program is triggering my script and it is passing arguments in that way

Comment: and it seems like there is not cleaner way in python to get arguments in that format (key value pairs separated by '='). I will either have to change format of input arguments or have to use the code that I mention in question.

Comment: @RAQ please see the update, as I may have found some information relevant to your specific needs. :)